# Using ORDER BY on an INNER JOIN SQL query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following three tables: Product, User and Purchased.

Product contains:

- A unique identifier (productID)
- A name (productname)
- A price
  (productprice)

User contains:

- A unique identifier (userID)

Purchased contains:

- Two identifiers noted as private keys, productID and userID
- A date of the record (creationdate)

My query should return a list of unique products that were bought on the retailer’s site since January 1st with most expensive product returned first.

My Query:

```
SELECT Product.productID, Product.productname, Purchased.creationdate
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Purchased 
ON Product.productID = Purchased.productID;
ORDER BY Product.productprice DESC;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of products, I would suggest `exists` rather than `join`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from purchased pu
              where pu.productId = p.productId and
                    year(pu.creationdate) = year(now())
             )
order by price desc;
```